# scp to a remote server; ssh: connect to host server@address.it port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: shell, ssh, remote-access, remote-server, scp

I'm having some trouble to use scp command in order to copy some file in a remote server.

the line i write on the terminal is

```
scp file.dat server@address.it:home/folder
```

and after about a minute it says the connection is lost due to time out

using the option `-vvv` I get

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host server@address.it, user username, command scp -v -t home/folder
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "server@address.it" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to server@address.it [141.108.1.185] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 141.108.1.185 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host server@address.it port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

Seaching on the web, I found that the most common source for this problem are firewalls, but I checked them and it seems they are ok. Indeed I have

```
sudo ufw status
Stato: attivo

A                          Azione      Da
-                          ------      --
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

One last information, if I try to make the access to the remote server from my PC terminal using ssh, there are no problems, and there I have done simple operations like creating folders (not much more for now, since I have to copy some data from my PC to that server to work on it)

Answer (score 0):

As you well said, normally a timeout means a network or communication issue between the source and the target. I would run:

In the source server

```
Windows --> CMD --> tracert -h 30 -w 60 -4 IPaddressOFTarget
Linux   --> Terminal --> traceroute -4 -w 30 IPaddressOFTarget
```

Provide the output.
Regards

Comment: Hi, I've encountered the same problem. The output for that command is:  `traceroute to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, 30 hops max, 60 byte packets`. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

On DEBIAN 10 this is working fine:

**scp -r -P 2222 /DIRFILES remote-user@remote-host:/DIRFILES**

-r recursive
-P remote port
DIRFILES absolute path to folders